# Creating a new user in Fedora Linux

Tags: fedora, gnome, kde, users

I'm using Fedora Linux with KDE environment, I would like to create a new user with Gnome environment.

is that possible?

Comment: GNOME has nothing to do with user management. Could you elaborate what you mean "create a new user with Gnome environment"?

Comment: Defining the default desktop environment is handled by your display manager. Which one are you using? Use `systemctl status display-manager.service` in order to find out. (or `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`)

Comment: @MarcusMüller;
For example, I'm on the KDE interface with the X user, I want to add Y user with GNOME interface.

Comment: I think I need **adduser** to do that, but I don't know about **options**

Comment: what does "add Y user with GNOME interface" mean? I'm sorry, I don't understand!